# How to save dynamically added fields data using nsuserdefault or any other in ios, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have a app and it has two view controllers.in the first view controller there is a table view.table view row count is dynamic.that means it change time to time.as an example it can be 3, 4, 1, 8 like this.it changes according to the user selection.like follow.this time row count is 7.[image]

when user tap on a cell to add traveller details, it navigate to second view controller which include a form(first name, last name, email like that).then after user enters the details(form is like following)

[image]

and press the `done` button, entered details shoult save to `nsuserdefault`.if there is `n` number of (max :12) travellers, `n` number of details should save temperory.

1. is it possible with `nsuserdefault`, if it is possible, how can I do that.
2. are there any other ways to do this.

hope your help with.thank your very much.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is the possibility to save all details inside NSUserDefault. You just have to gather the data and put it inside NSUserDefault as an array:

```
NSArray *dataToSave = [self methodToTakeAllData];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataToSave forKey:@"allUsersData"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

then to read the data back to an NSArray:

```
NSArray *savedData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"allUsersData"];
```

but there is a better way of keeping data - Core Data.
You can read more about Core Data and the way to save data here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use SQLite or Core Data for saving such details. NSUserDefaults is not prefered if your traveller's details are private as NSUserDefaults are stored in plist in binary format, with no encryption, and is stored in your app’s directory. This means that any user can tinker with your NSUserDefaults with 5 minutes of their time.If you still want to use NSUserDefaults, you will have to maintain your traveller's data in the form of dictionary/array and save it like this`[[NSUserDefaults standarduserdefaults]setvalue:dictionary/array forkey:travellerId]` and finally `[[NSUserDefaults standarduserdefaults]synchronize]`